# Java replaceAll - Replace "/**" with ""

Tags: java, replaceall

I am currently doing comment analysis with some Java code and needed to do the following opperation:

```
comment = comment.replaceAll("/**", "");
```

But I am meet with this Exception:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character '*' near index 2
/**
  ^
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.String.replaceAll(Unknown Source)
    at commentCoupler.coupler.commentCriteriaForfilled(coupler.java:234)
    at commentCoupler.coupler.analyze(coupler.java:64)
    at commentCoupler.coupler.recursiveCoupler(coupler.java:27)
    at commentCoupler.coupler.recursiveCoupler(coupler.java:22)
    at commentCoupler.coupler.recursiveCoupler(coupler.java:22)
    at commentCoupler.main.main(main.java:16)
```

Edit: The exception also occurs when I do

```
comment = comment.replaceAll("**/", "");
```

and

```
comment = comment.replaceAll("*/", "");
```

Do anyone know why this happens and do anyone have a workaround?

Comment: You have to escape a meta char

Comment: `*` is a reserved character in regex. You need to escape it.

Comment: Why not use `replace()`?

Comment: @DrewKennedy I can't seem to escape *, eclipse tells me that is not a valid escape char.

Comment: @TheLostMind Habit? But that fixed the problem as also answered by aioobe

Comment: `"/\*\*"` is the regex you need, but because it's in a java String I think you'll need `"/\\*\\*"`. Annoying, I know. It's really funny trying to find '\' because you end up doing `"\\\\"`. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20669000/1858327) for better explanation.

Comment: @CaptainMan You are exactly right, however my problem was easier fixed by using `replace` instead of `replaceAll`

Comment: @Fruit For future reference ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) takes a regular expression, and `/**` isn't a valid regular expression.

If you just want to remove `/**`, use [`replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) instead.

Answer (score 2):

First parameter of "replaceAll" is a regular expression, and character "*" has a special meaning in regular expressions.

You can use something like this:

```
String a = "/**hola mundo/**, adios mundo";
String output = a.replaceAll("/\\*\\*", "");
System.out.println(output); // --> "hola mundo, adios mundo"
```

Comment: Ahh, thanks, I understand now. Forgot that * is the wildcard char in regex.

Comment: The reason this is the way it is is because the proper regex is `/\*\*` and the backslash needs to be escaped in the java string.

Answer (score 0):

```
comment = comment.replaceAll("/\**", "");
```

Comment: Eclipse answers: "Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )"

Comment: Not only is this regex but also a java string, \ must be escaped for java String level and * must be escaped for regex level. `/\\*\\*` is correct.

Comment: Besides the comments here, it is always preferable if you also explain your solution. If anything, it lets you think through your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Two things are wrong with this code:

```
comment = comment.replaceAll("/**", "");
```

1. `*` is a special regex character to match any number of any characters, based on the context that you are removing comments you want to match the literal `*` so you need your regex to be `/\*\*`.
2. Because this regex is inside a java String it will try to read `\*` as an escape code (like `\n` being newline character), but `\*` isn't one. It needs to be `\\*` instead, meaning the String should be `/\\*\\*`

This is correct.

```
comment = comment.replaceAll("/\\*\\*", "");
```

---

As an aside, even if `\*` was a valid escape code, the thing it got replaced with would be passed into regex, not `\*`. (e.g., if you put `\n` in the newline character would go into regex, not a backslash and a lowercase n.

---

You may want to go with something like this though

```
comment = comment.replaceAll("/\\**\\*/", "");
```

which would be removing `/* <stuff> */`. This catches doc-comments *and* regular multi-line comments in addition to removing the entire comment. It depends on how you've read the string though.